# Centrar Section Boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3

Actualmente tengo el siguiente Form

```
  <section class="contact bg-primary" id="contact">
     <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="enviar.php" method="POST">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Nombre *</label>
             <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email *</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div> 

           <div class="form-group">
               <label>Asunto *</label>
               <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mensaje *</label>
                <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
           </div>                        

           <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar" />
           </div>                      
      </div> 
</form>
    </section>
```

pero se ve de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con `<div class="center-block"></div>` pero sin exito

Version de Boostrap  * Bootstrap v4.0.0 (https://getbootstrap.com)
Desde ya gracias

Comment: qeu version de bootstrap estas usando?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez esto es de ayuda ?href="bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: nop, entra al archivo bootstrap.min.css debe salir comentado arriba la version

Comment: * Bootstrap v4.0.0 (https://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: ok te ayudo, te are un ejemplo con bootstrap 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es centrar el formulario, entonces puedes usar la clase `mx-auto` en el contenedor de sus elementos:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="contact bg-primary" id="contact">
     <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="enviar.php" method="POST">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 mx-auto">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Nombre *</label>
             <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email *</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div> 

           <div class="form-group">
               <label>Asunto *</label>
               <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mensaje *</label>
                <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
           </div>                        

           <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar" />
           </div>                      
      </div> 
</form>
    </section>
```

Dicha clase agrega el siguiente código CSS que básicamente lo centra horizontalmente:

```
.ml-auto, .mx-auto {
    margin-left: auto!important;
}

.mr-auto, .mx-auto {
    margin-right: auto!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes centrar sin utilizar css con d-flex justify-content-center

[image: Centrado de formulario con d-flex bootstrap]

```
<section class="contact bg-light pt-5 pb-5" id="contact">
 <form id="main-contact-form" class="bg-primary contact-form d-flex justify- 
  content-center" name="contact-form" action="enviar.php" method="POST">
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Nombre *</label>
         <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" 
        required="required">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email *</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" 
       required="required">
       </div> 

       <div class="form-group">
           <label>Asunto *</label>
           <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" 
        required="required">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Mensaje *</label>
            <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required="required" 
       class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
       </div>                        

       <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn- 
       primary btn-lg" value="Enviar" />
       </div>                      
  </div> 
  </form>
   </section>
```

Coloque d-flex justify-content-center en la etiqueta de form

Answer (score -1):

Mira est es un formulario centrado con bootstrap 4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="bg-primary" id="contact">
    <div id="container" class="container">
      <div class="row text-white">
        <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
          <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="enviar.php" method="POST">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nombre *</label>
              <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email *</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div> 

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Asunto *</label>
              <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Mensaje *</label>
              <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
            </div>                        

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar" />
            </div>                      

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Ahí esta El `col-sm-*` debe estar dentro de un `.row` y el row dentro de
 un `.container` no debe esta dentro de la etiqueta form. Ahi esta el ejemplo para que lo veas en pantalla completa. Saludos , espero que te sirva.

Comment: Esto parece más una ilusión visual o un "truco" para intentar centrar algo, pero no necesariamente lo está centrando. Agregar un offset no implica centrar (aún si el resultado es correcto).

Comment: pero esas son las opciones de centrado que da bootstap 4. Esto sin utilizar css externo , solo la libreria.

Comment: Falso, revisa la documentación de Bootstrap, o mi respuesta, por ejemplo.

Comment: pasame el link de la documentacion de bootstap 4 , para ver donde esta lo que dices con tu ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que si utilizas el buscador interno del sitio web de Bootstrap o Google, lo puedes encontrar tú mismo.

Comment: entonces no tienes bases, yo si tengo, ya que este ejemplo lo encontre en esta página , pero en ingles y solo lo modifique para que pudiera usarlo. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389464/align-the-form-to-the-center-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: Tu -1 es más que merecido. Ni siquiera entendiste lo que exponen en dicho enlace. Para próximas preguntas revisa primero la documentación oficial y luego sí otras fuentes.